# Turning on syntax highlighting

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, syntax-highlighting

On this particular site, I think it is absolutely critical to have syntax highlighting work, automatically if possible.

Comment: how many languages are we going to face?

Comment: @LRE: The same amount as StackOverflow?  How do they handle it over there?

Answer (score 18):

We have turned this on - I will import the language specific prettify hints later.

Comment: Thankyou @Geoff Dalgas

Comment: Didn't feel like starting a separate question, but I'd like to know. What does "language specific prettify hits" mean specifically?

Comment: @Inaimathi see here:  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72082/changes-to-syntax-highlighting

Answer (score 3):

This probably just slipped the mind of the admins, since most of the new SE sites aren't code related.