# Meta code highlighting

Tags: feature-request, meta, syntax-highlighting

It appears that we don't have code highlighting in Meta

In [this answer](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6962/18427) to [Your vote matters!](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6943/your-vote-matters) the `<!-- language: lang-sql -->` was added to a block of SQL code, but the highlighting doesn't appear to be turned on for the Meta site.

[image: No SQL Syntax Highlighting]

We regularly use the SEDE Database to get statistics, I think that we all agree it would be nice to see the code highlighting in Meta.

If this is just an issue of turning it on for Meta, please, turn it on.

---

**Linked Meta:** [Turning on syntax highlighting](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16/turning-on-syntax-highlighting)

Comment: Probably a remnant of [this](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/30/23788) (5 years later!)